# Tableau dashboard sharing with multiple clients

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau online. There is one dashboard which needs to be shared with 50 external vendors just by changing vendor id in filter.

My requirement is that vendor should not be able to see data of other vendors.There are few ways that I am thinking to solve this problem but wanted to know the best option to minimize licensing cost.

1. Create multiple users in tableau online but then for every new user there is a licensing cost involved
2. Create 50 different dashboards and using a custom web portal, displaying the dashboard which belongs to that vendor. In this there is a risk that if vendor decodes the dashboard URL pattern they can easily see dashboards for others.

I wanted to get inputs on #3 on what can be done to achieve this goal keeping each vendor data in isolation.

Comment: Not to be nitpicking, but what you are trying to do/hack, will very likely violate Tableau's EULA... I get what you are trying to do, and IMHO this is one of the biggest downsides of Tableau: the costs of licenses for individual uses just looking/interacting with the dashboard is often out of proportion (although with (at least) Tableau Server there are now some option for cheaper "simpler" licenses for just viewing/interacting)

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might consider is a modification of your number 2. You could create 50 different dashboards and put a unique username and password on each one. This is process is described below and [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/218549) on the Tableau community forums by Sayali Dengale. As Niels mentioned in the comments above I think this would be in violation of the Tableau EULA.

> Just follow these steps:
>
> 1> Create sheets for your dashboard.
>
> 2> Go on that sheet for which you want to set password.
>
> 3> Create calculated parameter, give data type as 'String' and put current value as blank.

[image: Image 1]

> 3> Repeat the same procedure for password as follows

[image: Image 2]

> 4> create calculated field for username, with parameter username:

[image: Image 3]

> 5> Repeat the same procedure for password:

[image: Image 4]

> 6> Add calculated field named as Username to filter and select Custom value list. Give the username whatever you want to. Here i have given username as "Dev"

[image: Image 5]

> 7> Repeat the procedure for password. Here I had given password as "12345":

[image: Image 6]

> 8> Show both the parameters for username and password and You will see that the sheet is not visible when the username and password is not match. Since i had given username as "Sayali" instead of "Dev" the sheet is not visible.

[image]